# Storing multiple user inputs in R using readline

Tags: r, readline

I am using the readline() function to get input from a user and saving that input into a vector.

`your_current_guess=readline(prompt="odds or evens? ")`

How would I have a vector that saves each input from the user instead of only the most recent input?

Currently the only way I can think of is saving the input from x into a .txt file and then using the scan function to read from it, but I am certain that there would be a more simple and quick alternative.

Comment: Are you running this `readline` command in a `for` loop? Maybe you can try `your_current_guess[i] = readline(prompt="odds or evens? ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use select.list. But if you need multiple user inputs, you need to put that in a loop.

```
select.list(c("odd", "even"), multiple = F )
```